# GSON not retrieving the key in the linkedHashMap<object, String> as object. Instead retrieved as String

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gson

I was trying to send a LinkedHashMap through Gson from one activity. But in another activity, when I am trying to get the key of the LinkedHashMap, it is retrieved as a key of type String and not as a key of type Object. I have presented my code below.

Activity 1:

```
    LinkedHashMap<TravelMode, String> polyPoints=(LinkedHashMap<TravelMode, String>) gData.values().toArray()[0];
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type entityType= new TypeToken< LinkedHashMap<TravelMode, String> >(){}.getType();
    String list = gson.toJson(polyPoints,entityType);
    mapIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, list);
```

Activity 2:

```
    String str= getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Type entityType= new TypeToken< LinkedHashMap<TravelMode, String> >(){}.getType();
    LinkedHashMap<TravelMode, String>polypoint = gson.fromJson(str, entityType);
```

This is the Error I am getting while executing my program

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException) com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3 android
```

TravelMode:

```
   class TravelMode implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String travelMode;

    /**
     * @return the travelMode
     */
    public String getTravelMode() {
        return travelMode;
    }

    /**
     * @param travelMode the travelMode to set
     */
    public void setTravelMode(String travelMode) {
        this.travelMode = travelMode;
    }

    public TravelMode(String travelMode) {
        super();
        this.travelMode = travelMode;
    }
}
```

Please help me out folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Gson` has trouble with serialization of Map `keys` if they are custom objects. The default process would invoke `toString()` on your key and since key's `toString()` isn't overridden you might be getting an output like: `TravelMode@138532dc` and hence the error.

To get over this issue you would have to implement Gson Custom Serializer and Deserializer (see the [user guide here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization) and their recommendation for other other Library classes as well).

Or use `Map<String, String>` for your implementation.